# Ampersand URL parameters in document function

Tags: xslt

If I want to load a document into a variable, I can use

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="document('http://www.mySite.com/file1.xml')" />
```

=> works, I can use -

```
<xsl:value-of select="$var1//myNodeName"/>
```

but now I need to use a URL with parameter.
and the following tests do not work -

```
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="document('http://www.mySite.com/getfile.cgi?param1=val1&param2=val2')" />
```

=> does not work - EntityRef: expecting ';'

```
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="document('http://www.mySite.com/getfile.cgi?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2')" />
```

=> does not work - warn for wrong URL - 
     http://www.mySite.com/getfile.cgi?param1=val1&param2=val2:1: 
     why does it add :1: ???

**My Question:**
How do I replace the & entity to make the **document()** function work?

---

Update:
according to -
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/5421-Ampersand-in-XSLT
the solution is to store the URL as a variable, then output it disablig output escaping.
e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?param1=1&amp;param2=2" />
<xsl:value-of select="$test" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

but, how can I apply this solution with document() parameter?

---

Update 2:

I parse it using PHP -

```
<?php
Header('Content-type: text/xml');

// http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('http://www.mySite.com/devices.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('mergedocs.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>
```

The error I get [note the amp within the URL]:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://mySite/myPhpFile.php
Line Number 2, Column 1:<b>Warning</b>:  XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [<a href='xsltprocessor.transformtoxml'>xsltprocessor.transformtoxml</a>]: 
http://siteIp/cgi-bin/getfile.cgi?p1=v1&amp;p2=v2:1: parser error : Document is empty 
in <b>/home/.../myPhpFile.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  Encoding the `&` as `&amp;` _is_ the correct approach, the URL retrieved by the processor will be the correct one with `val1&param2`.  I suspect the `:1:` isn't part of the URL but rather part of the warning message i.e. `problem at <url>:<line-number>: <description of problem>`.  What exactly is the warning message printed?

Comment: "parser error : Document is empty" - and what do you get if you retrieve `http://siteIp/cgi-bin/getfile.cgi?p1=v1&p2=v2` yourself?  Again, the `amp;` isn't necessarily in the URL that PHP is trying to retrieve - since the error message is itself HTML any `&` characters in the message will need to be escaped as `&amp;` at the point where the error message is sent to the browser.

Comment: I do get the file. Is there a way to use disable-output-escaping with the parameter to document function?

Comment: No, and even if there were you don't need to - the XSLT processor is already requesting the correct URL (with `&`, not `&amp;`). There must be something else getting in the way, such as a firewall rule on the server running the PHP that prevents it from being able to fetch the file, or maybe some sort of content negotiation or user agent sniffing in the cgi script (if the processor uses a different Accept header from your browser).

Comment: You were right. I receive empty document probably because of permission policy in the remote site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using external XML uri with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522277/using-external-xml-uri-with-variables)

Answer (score 0):

> Encoding the & as &amp; is the correct approach, the URL retrieved by the processor will be the correct one with val1&param2. I suspect the :1: isn't part of the URL but rather part of the warning message i.e. problem at ::